# How to save a value from an API request, then use that value for next run and replace with new run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pagination

I'm not sure how to go about this but I have the below code, the first run doesn't require a scroll token but then to go to the next page I need the scroll token from the 1st page to use to get the 2nd page, and the 2nd page scroll_token to get the 3rd etc, until the last page which doesn't have a scroll_token:

```
search_url = 'https://api/v3/videos'
    
search_headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "Authorization": "bearer token"}  

data = {"query":{
            "include_filter":{
                "creator_list": 1}},
"scroll": {
"scroll_token": "SCROLL_TOKEN_VALUE_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE"
}
}
```

What would be the best strategy to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case? is this all going to be used within one run of a python script. My first idea is to define a function as a generator to get you each page lazily

```py
def get_pages():
    search_url = 'https://api/v3/videos'
    search_headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "bearer token"}  
    data = {
        "query":{
            "include_filter":{
                "creator_list": 1
            }
        }    
    }
    response = foo(search_url, headers=search_headers, params=data) # some web request function
    while 'scroll_token' in response:
        yield response
        data['scroll_token'] = response['scroll_token']
    yield response # one last time


for page in get_pages():
    # do something with each response
    print(page.status_code)
```

In this example get_pages() is a generator, which means it is essentially a list that has to be accessed in order and doesn't compute the next element in the list until it is asked for.